# remote X11 forwarding with OpenGL 3+

Tags: linux, opengl, ssh, x11

I have a machine running Ubuntu, where I can run windowed applications that use OpenGL 3+. However, when I try to run them remotely (`ssh -Y user@server.com`), OpenGL context initialization fails. After searching about this issue online, I'm not even sure if OpenGL support with remote X11 forwarding works very well. Has anybody successfully done X11 forwarding with OpenGL 3+? Is this supported at all? I have access to the source code of all the applications I want to run, so if there's a way to do something in the source code to make it work, that'd also be a viable solution. I'm especially interested in running windowed applications over ssh that use the glfw3 library.

EDIT: To clarify why this question is not just about general computing hardware and software and is not off-topic for this site, I have access to the source code and I'm open to alternatives that require developing my own solution. For example, @datenwolf proposed a solution that involves creating an EGL context, render to a FBO, call `glReadPixels` to get the pixels and send that to the client. I'm open to get solutions like this, which nobody would mention if this was posted on a site dedicated to general computing software.

Answer (score 3):

Indirect GLX opcodes have been specified only for OpenGL-1.x. OpenGL-2.x also may work via indirect GLX by virtue of all of the functions that make OpenGL-2.x were originally part of ARB extensions for all of which GLX opcodes have been specified. Above that nobody botherd to specify GLX opcodes, so there's no official support for this.

Comment: That's really bad. Do you know if there's any other way to achieve remote rendering using OpenGL 3?

Comment: @yewang: Since about 2 years (give or take) now, it's been possible to create X-serverless off-screen OpenGL contexts using EGL. You could create such a context, render to a FBO, `glReadPixels` into a X Pixmap and show that. The performance of this will of course be abysmal, if the connection is not on a local network. Depending on the kind of images you're generating stupid plain old X compression might do a decent job, if there are large areas of uniform color and similiar (beware of OpenGL dithering though).

Comment: @yewang: For best results you might want to consider to use a modern video codec and transmit the rendering as video. Of course that's not something supported by vanilla X11 (it'd be perfectly possible to make that a X11 extension though; a pretty useful one, too). But here's a nice idea: *Combine the render-offscreen-and-copy-to-X-pixmap with Xpra.* You can then even use MIT-SHM for the pixmap transfer and Xpra does the window forwarding for, using a high efficiency video codec.